Rapidly decreasing surface? Adaptation from Schwartz functions?
A foliation $\mathcal{F}$ on a smooth manifold $ X $ is a smooth decomposition of $ X $ into disjoint connected submanifolds $ \{L_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A} $, called leaves, where each leaf $ L_\alpha $ is locally diffeomorphic to
$ \mathbb{R}^k $ for some $ k \leq n $. The local trivialization of the foliation is given by a smooth submersion
$$
\phi: U \to \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^{n-k},
$$
where $ U \subset X $ is a local chart.
Assume $X=(0,1)^3$ and $\partial X=[0,1]^3-(0,1)^3$ and our foliation $\mathcal F$ satisfies the condition:
$$
\lim_{p \to \partial X} L_\alpha(p) = \{v_i, v_j\},
$$
where $ L_\alpha $ are the leaves in $ \mathcal{F}$ and $v_i=(1,1,1)$ and $v_j=(0,0,0)$ where $v_i,v_j\subset \partial X.$ Then in some rigorous sense the $L_{\alpha}$ decay to zero rapidly, if we choose a "direction" for example a flow that maps points on the $L_{\alpha}$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$.
This is similar to what's called a Schwartz space, which is the space of rapidly decreasing functions. And rapidly decreasing here can be made precise.

Is there an adaptation of this to rapidly decreasing surfaces, specifically does the example I gave work?

I was thinking to consider the space of all conservative vector fields on $L_{\alpha}$ and use the solutions to be classes of rapidly decreasing functions on the surfaces but couldn't figure out how to proceed from there.
Here's a schematic diagram showing a single leaf, $L$, with $v_i$ and $v_j$:

